# Question on String Operation

Tags: java

My understanding of java String got  wrong when i see this code.
I am not sure how this is happening.
Can anyone explain why is so?.

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str=null;

        System.out.println(str+"Added");
    }
}
```

**output:nullAdded**

Comment: Please elaborate what you actually expected, so that we can understand your confusion better.

Comment: The OP is obviously expecting `Added` to be printed, not `nullAdded` (in bold below the code).

Answer (score 11):

String concatenation treats a null reference as if it were "null" in Java. From the [docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for `StringBuilder.Append(String)`:

> The characters of the String argument
>   are appended, in order, increasing the
>   length of this sequence by the length
>   of the argument. If str is null, then
>   the four characters "null" are
>   appended.

Basically your code is similar to:

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str=null;

        System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append(str)
                                              .append("Added")
                                              .toString());
    }
}
```

Does that make it clearer?

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that when you use the `+` operator, both operands are converted to a string (if required) via `String.valueOf` method.  This returns the four-character string "null" for a null reference, rather than an actual null reference.

Thus `null + "Added"` is equal to `"null" + "Added"` and hence `"nullAdded"`.

Comment: Tony the Pony(...) is actually correct about the little details, it's not String.valueOf() but StringBuilder which causes the "null" to appear.

Comment: It depends what level of the stack you're looking at. In 1.5.0_06, at least, the StringBuilder implementation is return append(String.valueOf(obj)); which is why I listed valueOf as the method performing the null conversion. Arguably Jon's is more correct from an "interface" point of view, whereas I'd maintain mine is more correct from an "implementation" point of view; and I consider the latter more appropriate to this level of question.

Comment: Had to check, .append(Object obj) uses String.valueOf(obj); which internally is merely `return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();`, however .append(String str) copies characters directly. Meh, we're both right.

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to do is initialise the string with the empty string:

```
String str = "";
```

Comment: You mean String str = ""; as the '' is for chars.

Answer (score 0):

Java will/had always when concatanating a string converted null objects into the string null. via String.valueOf.

Java knows it is concatenating into a string, so even if the null is at the start (not at the end) of the expression it will still convert it to null.

you don't get a nullpointerException since no operation is called on the null object. A Little strange I know. but it is what it is.

[link: concat null and String](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/StringconcatenationThecontainsnull.htm)

Answer (score -1):

String variable str is given the null value.

When you print it, the String#toString() converts that to the string 'null', and appends the string "Added".  The result is

```
nullAdded
```

Comment: Thanks Jim,you are right.since we=hen i tried with creation an object of string,it gives only the Added as output.

Comment: The result is correct, but your explanation is wrong. There's no 'default toString()' method, which converts null references to the string "null".

Comment: toString on which instance? The null reference? Nice try, but still wrong.